# how to properly validate a checkbox values

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to upload a `checkbox` value to my `db`, it's uploading properly but does not get validated. If I did not check anything it still `POST`s the rest of the values on my other fields instead of alerting me to select from my checkboxes. I have all setup just not working properly. Am I validating the `checkbox` value properly?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<table width="200">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Verification[]" value="Test1" id="Verification_0" />
                BuildServerPath</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Verification[]" value="Test2" id="Verification_1" />
                File Exist</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Verification[]" value="Test3" id="Verification_2" />
                WBS Code</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Verification[]" value="Test4" id="Verification_3" />
                UAT Contact</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is how I `POST` it, I have two options

```
$Verification = implode('\r', $_POST['Verification']);
```

OR

```
$verify=""; 
$flag=0; 
foreach($Verification as $entry){ 
    $verify .= $entry."\r"; 
    $flag=1; 
} 
if($flag==1){ 
    $verify=rtrim($verify); 
}
```

Now, here is how I try to validate it. This type of validation works for my `radio button` and `text fields`; `document.form1.verify.value==""` gets changed to `verify` or `Verification` depending on the post method I used

```
function validateDBLoad()
{
    if ((document.form1.verify.value == "")
    {
        alert('Please fill up all the fields..');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Ticket upload Successful.');
        return true;
    }
}
```

I also tried to follow steps here: [Checkbox validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956128/checkbox-validator) but does not seem to work with my already setup validation code, it's giving me the alert to "Select a checkbox, please!" but at the same time uploading my other values,

Here is the `js` that I tried,

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('my-form').getElementsByTagName('input');
var checked = 0;
for (var i = 0, length = inputs.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].getAttribute('type') !== 'checkbox') {
       continue;
    }

    if (inputs[i].checked) {
        checked++;
    }
}

if (checked === 0) {
   alert('Select a checkbox, please!');
}
```

Comment: Your code is Good, but not professional. see [Simple Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234622/simple-javascript-checkbox-validation). I suggest you to learn **jquery** and then use class for your checkboxes and then validate all of them at one time with one code. ☻

Comment: where is your id my-form..

Comment: @Kermani you're right I'm still not a professional at this, my form also contains other fields such as `text field`, `radio button`, and a combo box they are all validating properly with my existing code, but can you explain how I can validate my checkboxes and my other fields using what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do this

```
if(document.querySelectorAll('#my-form input[type=checkbox]:checked').length===0){
   alert("Please select atleast one checkbox");
   return false;
}
if(validationForYourOtherFieldsIsNotFine){
   alert("Other validations will happen here");
   return false;

}
```

Comment: that can be good but i also have other fields to validate not just checkbox, it will work with my checkbox but just cant incorporate it to my existing validation code

Comment: For other fields you can have different if conditions simple.